# How to fetch IIS Start log for a corresponding IIS Stop log in Azure Log Analytics outside of Alert's monitoring time period

Tags: azure, iis, azure-log-analytics, azure-data-explorer, kql

I'm working on configuring an Azure Log Analytics alert (using KQL) to capture the IIS Stop & Start events (from `Events` table) in my OMS Workspace, and if the alert query finds that there's no corresponding IIS Start event log generated from a PaaS Role for a particular IIS Stop event log- the user should get notified by an alert so that he can bring IIS back up.

**Problem:** Let’s say I setup my alert to run over a Time Period & Frequency of 15mins. If the alert triggered at 10:30AM, that means it will scan the IIS logs from 10:15:01 AM to 10:29:59 AM. Now, suppose an IIS Stop event got logged in around 10:28 AM, then the respective IIS Start log (if any) will be logged in after a couple of minutes around 10:31AM or 10:32 AM – and hence it will go out of the alert’s monitoring time period. This will create a false positive failure scenario. (IIS got started back but my alert didn’t captured the Start event log). And thus, it might lead to some unnecessary IIS Start/Reset operations on my PaaS roles.

Attaching a representative quick sketch to explain it figuratively.

[image: IIS_Start_Stop_Events_issue]

Please let me know if there's any possible approach to achieve this. Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please add a sample of the data?

Comment: @TomerShetah - I'm sorry but I can't share the actual logs due to security reasons. But the problem statement described above explains the complete problem. Please let me know if there are any questions/confusions lying around and I can provide the clarifications.

Comment: Did you manage to find the solution to this problem?

Comment: @JustinMathew - Nope, not yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Current implementation as follows.

[image]

Here we can see False Alert generated at 10:30.

You can see the below approach, where we select last 10 minutes data(Overlapped) every 5 minutes.

[image]

For the below case you can generate the alert

[image]

See if its helping you.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I'll give this a go and will update you further.